# Embedded Google Map will no longer display

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

I have included in my app an Ionic Modal which consists of a Google Map with one marker, centred on a given point where there is a marker; clicking on a marker displays the address. This worked perfectly a few days ago, now I just get a blank page (nothing in the console) although I have not changed the relevant code. I am using Google to Geocode an address string first. This seems to work as 'results' is displayed in the console. Any help would be appreciated.

The below function is in a controller and is called when a button is pressed, opening a modal which is supposed to display the map.

```
     $scope.displayAddress = function(request) {
        var address = processAddress(request);
        var map;

        $scope.modal.show();

        // Now need to geocode the address.
        console.log(document.getElementById('map'));
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
           if (status == 'OK') {

              map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                 center: results[0].geometry.location,
                 zoom: 15
              });

              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                 map: map,
                 position: results[0].geometry.location
              });

              var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                 content: address
              });

              marker.addListener('click', function() {
                 infoWindow.open(map, marker);
              });
           } else {
              console.log("Error: " + status);
           };
        });
     };
```

HTML:

```
    <ion-modal-view>
<ion-header-bar>
    <h1 class="title">Client's Address</h1>
    <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="closeModal()">Close</button>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content>
    <div class="lesson-requests__address-map-wrapper">
        <div id="map" class="lesson-requests__address-map"></div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Wrapper has width, height = 100%

Comment: Your HTML is invalid `class-"lesson-requests__address-map-wrapper"` should be `class="lesson-requests__address-map-wrapper"`.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.  [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zmmonx1x/) containing your code snippet.

Comment: Yes my mistake. The problem still remains though. I tried adding the wrapper div while troubleshooting. I have updated my original post for greater context. I tried adding your addDomListener but it doesn't trigger at all then.

Comment: The issue is your HTML/CSS.  The map div doesn't have a size, unless you take percentage sizes all the way up to the `<html>` tag or to a fixed size element.

Comment: Thanks... somehow this was nevertheless working before but changed it now.

Comment: Perhaps the CSS changed